# Gscatter plot Matlab with different colors of clusterdata

Tags: matlab

I have this matlab code which should draw the two cluster data with different colors.

```
alldata = csvread('ClimaticData.csv') ; 
NumCluster = 2; 
dist = pdist(alldata, 'euclidean');
GroupsMatrix = linkage(dist, 'complete');
clust = cluster(GroupsMatrix, 'maxclust', NumCluster); 
E = evalclusters(alldata,clust,'CalinskiHarabasz') ;
gscatter (alldata(:,1),alldata(:,2),clust)
```

But it seem that the colors are not ok. I have marked here in the picture which cluster they should have the same color. How can I change that?

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to tell you, given that we cannot see your data. The problem seems to lie in either the call to `linkage()`, which generates the Gaussian Mixture components, or in the call to `cluster()`, which uses the generated GM components to perform the actual clustering. [`cluster()`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.cluster.html) has decent examples in its docs, try to follow those and see whether that improves the clustering.

Comment: I have now written this code in Matlab. And it seems that this solution works:  GMModel = fitgmdist(alldata, 2);
idCluster = cluster(GMModel,alldata);
gscatter(alldata(:,1),alldata(:,2), idCluster, 'bg','xo')

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question! [This is actually encouraged by the Stack Overflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I have now written this code in Matlab. And it seems that this solution works:

```
alldata = csvread('ClimaticData.csv') ; 
NumCluster = 2;  % <-----change cluster number here 
dist = pdist(alldata, 'euclidean');
GroupsMatrix = linkage(dist, 'complete');
clust = cluster(GroupsMatrix, 'maxclust', NumCluster); 
E = evalclusters(alldata,clust,'CalinskiHarabasz') ;

GMModel = fitgmdist(alldata, 2);
idCluster = cluster(GMModel,alldata);
gscatter(alldata(:,1),alldata(:,2), idCluster, 'bg','xo')
```

Maybe someone has a nicer solution, but in any case it works.